# Filtrar Foreign Key

Tags: python, django

Boa tarde...estou tentando fazer um filtro atraves ForeignKey, 
que me retorne somente itens que nao constam no cadastro de alocacoes,
estou usando Select2...mas não consigo filtrar...

tenho 3 models: sala, turma e Alocar

quero fazer alocações a partir deles, e no pop up, so quero que apareça 
itens que nao foram alocados ainda

model alocacao

```
class Alocar(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    data = models.DateField('Data', auto_now=True, blank=True)
    turma = models.ForeignKey(Turma, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    sala = models.ForeignKey(Sala, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    criada = models.DateTimeField('Criada', auto_now_add=True)
    alterada = models.DateTimeField('Alterada', auto_now=True)
```

model turma

```
class Turma(models.Model):
    turma = models.CharField('Código', max_length=8, unique=True)
    curso = models.CharField('Curso', null=False, max_length=50)
    periodo = models.CharField('Periodo', null=False, max_length=50)
    disciplina = models.CharField('Disciplina', max_length=50)
    qtdalunos = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField('Qtd')
    professor = models.CharField('Professor', max_length=50)
    alocada = models.BooleanField('Alocada', default=False)
    internet = models.BooleanField('Internet', default=False)
    projetor = models.BooleanField('Projetor', default=False)
    computador = models.BooleanField('Computador', default=False)
    criada = models.DateTimeField('Criada', auto_now_add=True)
    alterada = models.DateTimeField('Alterada', auto_now=True)
```

model sala

```
class Sala(models.Model):
    bloco = models.ForeignKey(Bloco, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    sala = models.CharField('Sala', max_length=50, unique=True, help_text="Descrição")
    capmaxima = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField('Cap. Máxima:')
    disponivel = models.BooleanField('Disponivel', default=True)
    internet = models.BooleanField('Internet', default=False)
    projetor = models.BooleanField('Projetor', default=True)
    computador = models.BooleanField('Computador', default=False)
    criada = models.DateTimeField('Criada', auto_now_add=True)
    alterada = models.DateTimeField('Alterada ', auto_now=True)
```

form

```
from django_select2 import forms as s2forms
import select2.fields
import select2.models
from django_select2.forms import Select2Widget



class AddAlocForm(forms.ModelForm):


    class Meta:
        model = Alocar
        fields = ('turma','sala','dia','horario')

        widgets = {
            'turma': Select2Widget,
            'sala': Select2Widget,
            'dia': Select2Widget,
            'horario': Select2Widget,
        }
```

observe o pop up, o item em destaque, nao é para aparecer na lista,

[image: filter pop up]

Comment: Se os itens não foram cadastrados os dados que os descrevem existem aonde? Talvez você deva reformular sua pergunta.

Comment: Obrigado amigo... segui o teu conselho e acrescentei mais codigo...estava bem dúbil mesmo –

Comment: Como uma sala é alocada?

Comment: @Italo Lemos Boa noite...no model alocar..há a chave estrangeira, da turma e da sala...é no model que são averiguadas as disponibilidade sala, horario, dia...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vamos lá
Primeiro ponto, não há necessidade `django_select2` duas vezes, basta usar como a documentação recomenda:

```
from django_select2 import forms as s2forms
```

e então você chama o Widget dessa maneira

```
s2forms.Select2Widget
```

Para filtrar do jeito que você quer, o seu campo turma é um ModelChoiceField então você pode definir um `queryset` para eles da seguinte maneira dentro da classe do seu form:

```
class AddAlocForm(forms.ModelForm):
    turma = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Turma.objects.filter(alocada=False))
```

Apenas turmas não alocadas irão aparecer no seu campo como opção de escolha.

Referência: [ModelChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield)

`

Comment: ....Boa tarde...mesmo o atributo TURMA sendo uma FOREIGNKEY no model...eu posso fazer desse jeito?

Comment: Sim @ElvisDba todo campo que representa uma relação entre dois models ele pode ser do tipo  ModelChoiceField ou ModelMultipleChoiceField.

Comment: Obrigado meu nobre....@Italo Lemos ...não querendo abusar da sua boa vontade..teria como me ajudar nesse outro post????  ... Erro ao renderizar com select2 Django....